# How to find a list or log of all site collections with SPFX extension deployed?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions, spfx-custom-property-pane

We deployed a spfx extension (Add-PnPCustomAction Location "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer" ) to multiple site collections manually, is there a way to use powershell to pull extensions and maybe even spfx webparts added to each site collection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to list them for all site collections with one command but you should be able to use Get-PnPCustomAction on each site collection. Something like this.

```
$adminSite = "https://TENANT-admin.sharepoint.com"
$extName = "NameOfCustomiserApplicationCustomizer"
$creds = Get-Credential
$extenstions = @()

Connect-PnPOnline –Url $adminSite –Credentials $creds
Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -notlike my.sharepoint.com" | % {
    $site = $_.Url
    Write-Output "Processing $site"
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site -Credentials $creds
    $siteExtensions = Get-PnPCustomAction | Where-Object { $_.Location -eq "ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer" -and $_.Name -eq $extName }
    $siteExtensions | % { 
        $extenstions += [pscustomobject]@{ Site=$site; Customiser=$_.Name }
    }
} 

$extenstions | Export-Csv -Path "C:/temp/application-customisers.csv"  -NoTypeInformation
```